# raw socket. ip header when to use hton

Tags: c, network-programming, raw-sockets

I am new to raw socket, and I am playing around with ip header. 
I noticed that 
  `ip->ip_hl = sizeof(struct ip) >> 2 //works fine;`
however 
`ip->ip_hl = hton(sizeof(struct ip) >> 2) //will not work;`

what i dont understand is that why not convert all the numbers to network order instead of host order in this case?
what's the general rule to judge when to use network order/host order?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htons` is for 16-bit values. `htonl` is for 32-bit values. As for `hton` (no suffix), I'm not even sure that exists.

The header length occupies only one byte (actually *part* of one byte). You don't need to flip any bytes to get it into the right form. Accordingly, there is no macro like `htons` or `htonl` for 8-bit values.